# Storing images in Android 11 and above usign android java

Tags: java, android

I am developing an android app using `java` and I want to save captured image from my `CameraActivity` into phone storage. Everything is working fine until Android 10 but when I run the app on Android 11 and above, I can not save the image in the storage. I have read about it and android docs said that from android 11 and onwards, you have to use `Scoped Storage` and for that I am using `MediaStore` for storing the images but it gives me the following error:

> /external/file/DemoPicture.jpeg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or
> directory)

Here is my code to save the image in Android 11 and above:

```
File picture;
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                    ContentResolver resolver = activity.getContentResolver();
                    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "DemoPicture.jpeg");
                    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
                    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH,
                            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
                                    + File.separator
                                    + getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)
                                    + File.separator + "imgfolder");
                    contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
                    contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
                    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.IS_PENDING, 1);
                    Uri imageUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
                    OutputStream outputStream = resolver.openOutputStream(Objects.requireNonNull(imageUri));

                    try {
                        outputStream.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        contentValues.clear();
                        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.IS_PENDING, 0);
                        resolver.update(imageUri, contentValues, null, null);
                    }

                    Uri external = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                    picture = new File(external.getPath(), "DemoPicture.jpg");


                } else {
                    File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
                    picture = new File(path, "DemoPicture.jpg");

                    path.mkdirs();

                    output = new FileOutputStream(picture);
                    output.write(bytes);

                }


                File newFile = new File(picture.getAbsolutePath()); // this line gives me the error
```

Comment: `picture = new File(external.getPath(),...` That will not work. And you cannot use the File class for an uri. Use Uri imageUri to access your file.

Comment: Further you dont need mediastore on Android 11+. Your File code for Pictures directory will work too.

Answer (score 0):

After spending hours, I finally got it working. No need to use `MediaStore` Api. Just use `getExternalFilesDir(null)` which returns the complete path of your app and save your image in that path.